# Can special cards with "discard" label in King of Tokyo be saved until later?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

In King of Tokyo, when I buy a special card with a "discard" label, do I have to use that card at the time of purchase? Can I save it to use later?

I infer from the rule book that I can save it... But the official text doesn't exactly state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules explicitly state that Discard cards are immediately used and discarded.

It's in a text box right above "3. Buying cards".

Comment: Thanks. The instructions I have say "monsters immediately resolve these then discard them". But I wasn't sure if that was immediately after purchase.